# Configure Strict Cors .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a public analytics web api (.Net Core 3.1) that captures basic analytics from my various web apps and sites (page views, etc). I'd very much like to configure cors in a more strict manner as I am well aware of the origins from where traffic should come. It's worth noting that I'm updating this application from `.Net Core 2.2` to `.Net Core 3.1`.

I have the following method in my `Startup.cs` file

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  ConfigureCors(services);
}

private void ConfigureCors(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas
  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
             builder => builder.WithOrigins(AppConfiguration.CorsOrigins)
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader());
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
      });
  }
```

`AppConfiguration` is a class I use to handle configurations and it grabs `json` values using the following:
`public string[] CorsOrigins => _config["CorsOrigins"].Split(',');`

In `appsettings.Development.json`, I have `"CorsOrigins": "*"`

I'd very much like to specify strict origins in the `appsettings.Production.json` and `appsettings.Staging.json` files.
E.g.
`"CorsOrigins": "https://subdomain.example.com,https://www.example.com,https://example.com"`, but on deployment, I get a status of `502` whenever by websites/apps hit the various endpoints.

`"CorsOrigins": "*"` works on local so there can't be anything wrong with the `Startup.cs` file as far as I'm aware.

**Update:** `"CorsOrigins": "*"` actually does not work for the staging or production environments either. Now I'm even more confused. To be clear, this is a `cors` question. The following worked fine before upgrading to `.Net Core 3.1`:

```cs
private void ConfigureCors(IServiceCollection services)
      services.AddCors(options =>
      {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
             builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowCredentials());
      });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you struggling with "consuming" your appsettings.ENVIRONMENT.json ( see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ) OR ... that the values in your appsettings.ENVIRONMENT.json file (for your specific CORS) are screwballing you?

Comment: @granadaCoder the consumption of app settings is golden, it's not playing nice with "*", or the array of origins in the form provided above as examples. I.e. if I debug, AppConfiguration.CorsOrigins has the expected value depending on the environment.

Comment: According to the documentation the CORS specification that setting origins to "*" (all origins) is invalid if the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is present. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware

Comment: @pbachman correct. In moving to .Net Core 3.1, AllowCredentials has been removed as it is not valid when "*" is used (see "Update" for before code). In my case, as the options are "\*", "example.com", etc, AllowCredentials can also not be used and has been removed (see current situation above the "Update" section. No Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is present in my request.

Answer (score 2):

Take care to place the UseCors at the right location. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> The call to UseCors must be placed **after** UseRouting, but **before**
> UseAuthorization.

As noted in the comments, allowing "*" as origin isn't allowed with AllowCredentials.

Here's a working example of a CORS configuration from my ASPNET Core 3.1 project. It does the config in the Configure method instead of ConfigureServices, but same content:

```
// Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    // etc
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // other configs

    app.UseRouting();

    // CORS configuration. Expects allowed origins as comma-separated list in config under 'Cors:AllowedOrigins'.
    string configuredOrigins = Configuration["Cors:AllowedOrigins"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Cors:AllowedOrigins");
    string[] origins = configuredOrigins.Split(',', ';').Select(i => i.Trim()).ToArray();
    app.UseCors(policy => policy
        .WithOrigins(origins)
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials() // Required by SignalR
        .WithExposedHeaders(CONTINUATION_HEADER_KEY) // Allow use of custom header
        .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(86400))); // Allow caching for 24 hours (depends on browser)

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    // other configs
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample. I'm afraid I still get `502` following the `between` UseRouting` and `UseAuthorization` rule. I've added an image to my post showing all the information of the failing request. For simplicity, I've reverted to using `AllowAnyOrigin` to rule out some possibilities as my `2.2` version was on `AllowAnyOrigin` too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a difficult question so there could be a number of reasons it doesnt work but Ive run into a similar issue and resolved its by altering the cors invocation in the Configure() function. The Configure() function is a gets called during runtime and acts as an http request pipeline so in some cases order of execution matters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-configure-method)

You could try the following:

Change the current:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();
      app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); //Move this line 

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
      });
  }
```

To:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); // Here

      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
      });
  }
```

Hence the first operation in the http pipeline would be to validate cors.
I rate this is a fair bet as from your question it sounds like you dont get an app initialise error but rather a runtime client request time error.
I dont know for certain if this will solve the problem but maybe it helps!

Comment: The docs state that "The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization."

Comment: Thanks @NoahStahl :) i never saw that! thanks for the assist - ive updated my answer to comply :)